# Compatibility between Class Diagram and Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

Do the `message` being passed between `objects` in `Sequence Diagram` match with the `methods` in `Class Diagram`?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes. Each message in a Sequence Diagram corresponds to a method in the Class Diagram.

In practice, showing everything in your Class Diagrams tends to make them unmanageable and hard to understand. For that reason, it is often best to leave out all the little details that aren't needed to bring your point across and that often includes some or all of the methods and/or properties that a class has.